# How to call Assembly.Load(Bytes[]) in SL 4 app?

Tags: .net, silverlight, security, reflection

I'm trying to use Assembly.Load(Byte[]) in a Silverlight 4 app and i'm getting MethodAccessException. As far as I understand that's because my app code is Transparent and this method is Critical. Is there any SafeCritical API to load assembly from byte array?

Then I want to create an instance of type (SL app doesn't have a compile time reference to it) that is inside dynamically loaded assembly and make that instance a current item for a  DataFrom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
  AssemblyPart assemblyPart = new AssemblyPart();
  assemblyPart.Load(new MemoryStream(yourByteArray));
```

Comment: How to create a type instance from this assemblyPart thing?

Comment: @fspirit:  use `Type.GetType(string)` to get a reference to the `Type` then `Activator.CreateInstance(Type)` to create an instance of that `Type`.